# Can anyone recognize these parts?

Tags: switch

I was repairing/replacing a set of switches. Two brass metal parts fell out. I don't know what they are or where they came from. I don't know if they are essential or not.

Does anyone recognize them?

[image: Brass metal strips]

Comment: Did your post get cutoff? Also, could you add photos please?

Comment: Yes, my post did get cutoff a bit. However, the real problem was that I did not know how to upload pictures. This should be fixed now.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What kind of a switch are we talking here? Where are you located?

Comment: Mr. Griscom, I wish I knew. I took out two single-pole switches and one 4 wire switch. I think the brass parts came from the 4 wire switch, but I am not sure. I live in Houston, Texas.

Comment: Were the wires held on by screws?  **Did you *remove* the screws?**

Comment: Captain nemo is looking for old switch contacts. , if they fell out time for new,

Comment: I ended up buying a new switch because I wasn't sure than I could reassemble the old one in a safe way. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

Those look like the metal contacts that the switch lever tips either up or down to make a contact - the pivot point looks to be the ends of the strip.

Comment: ...which means the switch is either seriously broken, or was taken apart far beyond what is needed to change wires. The majority I can think of would have to be pretty broken to get at those parts, as they are normally sealed in and not accessible for any sort of service other than replacing the whole switch...

Comment: Depends on the switch - have taken switches apart to clean contacts like that before. And the switched may only be held together with a couple of clips.

Comment: I ended up buying a new switch because I wasn't sure than I could reassemble the old one in a safe way. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.